# Add a page to another page

Tags: php, wordpress

Well guys, I was wondering how can I add a page to another.

Example: The "**Contact Us**" of my company will be based on the page "Service" from that bank ([Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTBc8.jpg)).

I wonder how I can create a separate page in the format of the example image (contact-content.php) and include in *page.php*, but with the condition if and only if it is the page "**Contact Us**".

I started writing the code but could not finish it:

This is my *page.php*

```
<?php get_header();?><!--AQUI FICA O HEADER-->



    <div id="content"><!--INICIO DIV CONTENT-->


        <div id="page_content"><!--INICIO DIV PAGE_CONTENT-->

            <?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>


                <span class="titulo"><?php the_title();?></span>
                <?php the_content();?>


            <?php endwhile; else:?>
            <?php endif;?>

        </div><!--FIM DIV SINGLE_CONTENT-->


    </div><!--FIM DIV CONTENT-->
```

I hope that you'd understand,
now,
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a shortcode.

Paste this code to your functions.php:

```
function my_show_page( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'page_id' => 0 ), $atts ) );
    $page = get_page( $page_id );
    return apply_filters( 'the_content', $page->post_content );
}

add_shortcode( 'my_show_page', 'my_show_page' );
```

And now, in any page or post, you can write:

```
[my_show_page page_id="999"]
```

999 is the id of the page to display.